# Get the current length from StringLengthAttribute in C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have ASP.NET website attribute in model:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "bla bla")]
[MinMaxLength(50,2000)]
public string TextDetail { get; set; }
```

And I have localized

```
public class MinMaxLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public MinMaxLengthAttribute(int minimum, int maximum)
       :base(maximum)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} must contain from  {2} to {1} characters."; //this text is localized, that is why I need to use special class
        MinimumLength = minimum;
    }
}
```

When I look into logs, I can found

```
Exception (level 0):
Message = bla bla must contain from 50 to 2000 characters.
```

I would like to log if user has written too short or too long string. Is there a way to log the current length of string in StringLengthAttribute?

Comment: Why are you creating the MinMaxLengthAttribute? Why don't you use StringLengthAttribute?

Comment: Because StringLengthAttribute as it is works only for site in English language, see comment. As I know I have to do such customization for custom localized messages. If there is simple solution, please tell me.

Comment: We use Resource files for our localized error messages all the time. Why can't this be done with StringLengthAttribute's error message as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, the solution is quite simple:

```
public class MinMaxLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    int? _stringLength = null;

    public MinMaxLengthAttribute(int minimum, int maximum)
        : base(maximum)
    {
        SetErrorMessage();
        MinimumLength = minimum;
    }

    void SetErrorMessage()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "{0} must contain {2} to {1} characters." +
               " It contains " + (_stringLength ?? -1) + " characters.";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (s != null)
        {
            _stringLength = s.Length;
            SetErrorMessage();
        }

        return base.IsValid(value);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string s = value as string;
        if (s != null)
        {
            _stringLength = s.Length;
            SetErrorMessage();
        }

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }        
}
```

And unittest:

```
using Common.Validators;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Test.Model
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTestDtaValidation
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMinMaxLengthAttribute()
        {
            MyModel model = new MyModel()
            {
                TextDetail = "a"
            };

            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var isValid = System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext, results, true);

            Assert.IsFalse(isValid);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);

            Assert.AreEqual("Description must contain from 5 to 10 characters. It contains 1 characters.", results[0].ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [MinMaxLength(5, 10)]
        public string TextDetail { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe we have different definitions of "quite simple," particularly when it comes to duplicating functionality already present in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `StringLengthAttribute` like below:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "bla bla")]
[StringLength(20000, MinimumLength = 50, ErrorMessage = "{0} must contain from  {2} to {1} characters.")]
public string TextDetail { get; set; }
```

And, if you want to show the current invalid value, you can use jQuery. There's no need for server-side code to do such simple thing.

Comment: Yes, your solution is more simple for custom localized message. It is good as well. But I didn't want to duplicate the localized text again and again. I just want to have one place with localization of data annotations. The question is about logging/tracing the behavior of users. I just want to know from log, it they put too short or too long strings into the form.

Answer (score -1):

The [`StringLengthAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute?view=netcore-3.1) class inherits from `ValidationAttribute` which can be localized from a resource string by using the `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName`. So your example becomes:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyStringsResource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MyTextDetailErrorMessage"]
    public string TextDetail { get; set; }
}
```

And in your localized `MyStringsResource` resources, have a string named `MyTextDetailErrorMessage` set to something like `"{0} must contain {2} to {1} characters."`.

If you need a more dynamic message in a derived class, you can construct your `MinMaxLengthAttribute` instance with the protected overload `ValidationAttribute(Func<string> errorMessageAccessor)` that lets you provide a function to look up the error message. Sorry, I have no experience with it to share.